# Expo Go app crashes on Android | No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After some unknown changes my app repeatedly crashes on the Expo Go app on Android only, iOS works fine. It breaks right after downloading the javascript bundle.

With the following error from adb logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-10-17 21:41:12.536 4780-4957/host.exp.exponent A/libc: /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r20/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type facebook::jsi::JSError: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal
    
    no stack" failed
2021-10-17 21:41:12.536 4780-4957/host.exp.exponent A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4957 (mqt_js), pid 4780 (st.exp.exponent)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.592 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG: pid: 4780, tid: 4957, name: mqt_js  >>> host.exp.exponent <<<
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 000bad94  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0009fc2e  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 000b78e9  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000b8294  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000b7dab  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 000b7a2e  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libfbjni.so (__gxx_personality_v0+158) (BuildId: 3546c1351f83366cb88b3802c4c63ee907e2db98)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 00034dab  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libjscexecutor_abi42_0_0.so (BuildId: 0afc290041ee8f03)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00034e62  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libjscexecutor_abi42_0_0.so (BuildId: 0afc290041ee8f03)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.704 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 0002e085  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libjscexecutor_abi42_0_0.so (facebook::jsc::JSCRuntime::evaluateJavaScript(std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<facebook::jsi::Buffer const> const&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> > const&)+629) (BuildId: 0afc290041ee8f03)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 00025cd0  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libjscexecutor_abi42_0_0.so (facebook::react::JSIExecutor::loadBundle(std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSBigString const, std::__ndk1::default_delete<facebook::react::JSBigString const> >, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >)+384) (BuildId: 0afc290041ee8f03)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 000b5401  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 000b6bcc  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 00078e9c  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 00068422  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::*)(), &(facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::run()), facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, facebook::react::Runnable>::JavaPart, facebook::react::Runnable, void>::_javaobject*>)+50) (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 00068389  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (facebook::jni::detail::FunctionWrapper<void (*)(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, facebook::react::Runnable>::JavaPart, facebook::react::Runnable, void>::_javaobject*>), &(facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::*)(), &(facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::run()), facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, void>::dispatch(facebook::jni::alias_ref<facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, facebook::react::Runnable>::JavaPart, facebook::react::Runnable, void>::_javaobject*>)), facebook::jni::detail::JTypeFor<facebook::jni::HybridClass<facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, facebook::react::Runnable>::JavaPart, facebook::react::Runnable, void>::_javaobject*, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+73) (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 00068333  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/lib/x86/libreactnativejni_abi42_0_0.so (facebook::jni::detail::MethodWrapper<void (facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::*)(), &(facebook::react::JNativeRunnable::run()), facebook::react::JNativeRunnable, void>::call(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+35) (BuildId: a7dea22b245b2ec7)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 000cf258  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/oat/x86/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+104)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.705 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #28 pc 009e3898  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/oat/x86/base.vdex (abi42_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.706 4964-4964/? A/DEBUG:       #40 pc 009e3a26  /data/app/~~ZiekYe0x1Z8XbtryZLj4Dg==/host.exp.exponent-jT1g_VBoSLB3h6CrOBOi_g==/oat/x86/base.vdex (abi42_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run+74)
2021-10-17 21:41:12.932 548-4971/system_process W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity host.exp.exponent/.experience.HomeActivity
2021-10-17 21:41:12.934 548-4971/system_process W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity host.exp.exponent/.experience.ExperienceActivity
2021-10-17 21:41:13.063 548-1284/system_process I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{d045a07 u0 host.exp.exponent/host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity}
2021-10-17 21:41:13.063 548-1284/system_process W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'd045a07 host.exp.exponent/host.exp.exponent.experience.ExperienceActivity (server)'
2021-10-17 21:41:13.064 548-3885/system_process D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=33, [ Capabilities: NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND Uid: 10121 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10121 RequestorPackageName: host.exp.exponent] ], android.os.BinderProxy@39fc18e)
2021-10-17 21:41:13.065 548-960/system_process D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=34, [ Capabilities: NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND Uid: 10121 AdministratorUids: [] RequestorUid: 10121 RequestorPackageName: host.exp.exponent] ], android.os.BinderProxy@9d2ddaf)
2021-10-17 21:41:13.084 548-2175/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process host.exp.exponent (pid 4780) has died: prcp TOP
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.11.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "compressorjs": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-camera": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~9.2.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~10.2.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-svg-uri": "^1.3.1",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-shared-element": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I don't really know where to start with debugging this. Looking at my code there doesn't appear to be an obvious error causing this. It runs just fine on iOS

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

I've tried:

- clearing cache multiple times.
- restarting phone
- running on different android devices

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, Numbers with underscore separators cause errors in android.

**NOT OKAY:**

```
const time = () => {
        if(!previous) return false
        if(!previous.message) return true
        if(!message.createdAt) {
            const t1 = previous.createdAt.toDate()
            const dt1 = new Date(t1.toString()), dt2 = new Date()
            return dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime() > 600_000;
        } else {
            const t1 = previous.createdAt.toDate(), t2 = message.createdAt.toDate()
            const dt1 = new Date(t1.toString()), dt2 = new Date(t2.toString())
            return dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime() > 600_000;
        }
    }
```

**OKAY:**

```
const time = () => {
        if(!previous) return false
        if(!previous.message) return true
        if(!message.createdAt) {
            const t1 = previous.createdAt.toDate()
            const dt1 = new Date(t1.toString()), dt2 = new Date()
            return dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime() > 600000;
        } else {
            const t1 = previous.createdAt.toDate(), t2 = message.createdAt.toDate()
            const dt1 = new Date(t1.toString()), dt2 = new Date(t2.toString())
            return dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime() > 600000;
        }
    }
```

[Numbers with underscore separators cause error on Android](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12042)

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable name that starts with a number on your JavaScript code.

[A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($). They can't start with a digit! Only subsequent characters can be digits (0-9)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Identifier_after_number)

Comment: That's not the case. My IDE would warn me about that. And if that were the case then iOS would also crash. It's only crashing on Android..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the underlying problem was exactly what @YourivdHeuvel explained in their answer, but it was in the popular [color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color) dependency.

```
Error: Unexpected token: name (_28) in file node_modules/color/index.js at 237:33
```

There's more detail [on the issue here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32044#issuecomment-917930572). It's a bit controversial because the maintainer [refuses to change](https://github.com/Qix-/color/issues/223#issuecomment-917981809) the [line in question](https://github.com/Qix-/color/blob/master/index.js#L272):

```
for (const [i, element] of rgb.entries()) {
    const chan = element / 255;
    lum[i] = (chan <= 0.039_28) ? chan / 12.92 : ((chan + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4;
}
```

since supporting underscore separators in numbers is part of [modern javascript syntax](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators).

A workaround is to downgrade `color` to `^3.2.1` (if you're not able to upgrade your React Native version or switch to the Hermes engine on Expo).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue, another possible cause is BigInt literals while using the JavaScriptCore JS engine. Hermes is the default now, but if you're still using JSC with the newer react native versions, the Babel config appears to switch BigInts to BigInt literals if they are for literal values (e.g., `2n` instead of `BigInt(2)`). This was happening for us in the buffer library which is used by many libraries. Switching to Hermes resolves it since Hermes supports BigInt literals now. If you must stay on JSC, I believe there's a Babel plugin to prevent the use of BigInt literals though we didn't end up using that.